# sqlalchemy + postgresql CASE statement error

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchmey to programmatically generate SQL statements to be executed in Postgresql. So far so good, but today I had to create and run some statements with `CASE .. WHEN ..  ELSE ..` structure within the SQL statement.

My original requirement was to create a time format from different time formats in a column so my sql string was as per below

```
sql_String = """select 
    text_field_1,
    case
        when time_field like '%AM%' then to_timestamp(time_field, 'FMHH12:MI:SS AM')::time
        when time_field like '%PM%' then to_timestamp(time_field, 'FMHH12:MI:SS AM')::time
        else to_timestamp(time_field, 'FMHH24:MI:SS')::time
    end as time_field
from 
    table_1"""
```

Using the following SQLAlchemy methods,

```
conn = pg_engine.connect()
trans = conn.begin()
conn.execute(sql_string)
trans.commit()
conn.close()
```

Tried the code above, and it works within Postgresql. But when I execute with SQL Alchemy I get a `TypeError: 'dict' object does not support indexing`

I tried a similar `CASE .. WHEN ..  ELSE ..` statement with a non-date/time column as well, same error.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you try running just the simple query `select text_field_1 from table_1`?  If this doesn't work, then the issue probably isn't just the query.

Comment: That works fine. Also when I run `select time_field from table_1`, that works fine as well.